# How I can generate a hash that returns always 24 characters with javascript for creating a mongo ObjectId?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, hash

Now I'm using https://github.com/emn178/js-md5 but it return 33 characters, I need 24 characters for generating always the same mongodb objectId.

There is a hashing algorithm that can accomplish this?

Now this is what I'm doing

```
const md5 = require('js-md5')
const ObjectID = require('bson-objectid')

const my_string = 'some text'
ObjectID(md5(my_string).slice(0, 24)) // Returns valid ObjectId
```

Comment: Why the MongoDB tag? Do you think you can supply this as an argument to `ObjectId()`? If so then this is not the way. I suggest you actually [read the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/).

Comment: I don't think there is any hashing algorithm which can provide you exactly 24 character digest.

Comment: Simply shorten your 33 characters using str.substr(0,24);

Comment: but,... Why md5 give you 33 chars???

Comment: surely it's 32 characters

Comment: @NeilLunn: but you can supply __arbitrary__ 24-char hex string to `ObjectId()`. Meteor, for example, does just this. Its object ids are entirely random.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev *"but you can supply arbitrary 24-char string to ObjectId()"*. **No you cannot**. Meteor ids are not `ObjectId()`. I suggest you try putting random strings into the method in any implemented language and learn something.

Comment: @NeilLunn: I updated my comment to clarify. Of course, it's a hex string. I challenge you to produce such 24-char hex string that will not be accepted by ObjectId function

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I think you should do some reading since you are incorrect

Comment: A related topic you may interest in: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3558/are-there-hash-algorithms-with-variable-length-output

Comment: @NeilLunn: here's a hex string which is first 24 chars of sha1 of `"foobar"`. And mongo shell happily eats it: `oid = ObjectId('3773dea65156909838fa6c22')`

Comment: @NeilLunn I updated the example

Comment: @user3561335 You cannot do it despite any other comment. The documentation link I give you tells you why. There is a specific format that is there for a reason. Of course you are free to create your own "unique hash" and use that as a key as much as you like. But unless the rules are followed, it's not an `ObjectId()`. The brief mention of "meteor" here is an example of something that uses it's own value for `_id` keys, but again those are **not** `ObjectId` compliant values or type.

Comment: @NeilLunn: "those are not ObjectId compliant values or type" - that is factually incorrect. Mongo server can't tell the difference between "true" object ids and "fake" ones. Whatever way you choose to create them, the only thing that matters is that they don't match any other previously created id. And here you are guarded by the unique index on `_id`.

Comment: I will add though that "cannot" is a strong word, and rather the case here is *"as long as it follows the rules"*. But if it does not construct in the same way, then it just is not an `ObjectId`

Comment: @NeilLunn: "There is a specific format that is there for a reason." - the "reason" is that the implemented scheme offers very good chances of obtaining a random non-yet-seen id. You should learn to see the forest behind the trees. And back your claims with _something_ :)